# wrap with widget issue in flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

When I wrap something with **wrap with widget** in flutter then random wrap appear.

Kindly tell me how to solve this issue.

[image]

Comment: If that's VSC, something has corrupted your snippets.  Or was this from the lightbulb menu "wrap with widget"?

Comment: It is from the lightbulb menu "wrap with widget".

Comment: @RandalSchwartz You have any idea how to solve this issue ?